# PHP Array parsing with foreach

Tags: php, facebook

I am doing an application using Facebook API that displays friends who liked the photo of the user.

I've used a code `$facebook->api('me/photos?type=uploaded&fields=likes,comments');` to display fetch data.

Then I use this loop to display the data.

```
foreach($likes_comments['data'] as $top) {
    if($top['likes'] != null){
        $array = $top['likes']['data'][0]['name'];
        echo $array;
    }
}
```

The problem is it only displays the first result of every array. I also want to display the `$top['comments']` What's wrong with my code?

Here is the link of my array: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nTzjX705

Comment: `$array[] = $top['likes']['data'][0]['name'];` then use `print_r($array)`

Comment: @aldrin27 I got this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KntwjGuR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sets of data you're iterating over here. The first set `$likes_comments['data']` is an array of likes/comments. To get the likes you need to iterate over `$likeData['likes']['data']` further. You can do the same for `$likeData['comments']['data']` for the comments in a separate loop. Using `var_dump` to inspect the array is probably going to be key to understanding the best way to iterate over which parts.

Here's an example to get all the likes...

```
foreach($likes_comments['data'] as $likeData) {
    if(isset($likeData['likes']['data']) && is_array($likeData['likes']['data'])){
        foreach($likeData['likes']['data'] as $like) {
            echo "$like[name]: $like[id]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Seems your answer doesn't work anymore. Please help me. thank you!

Comment: So use `$likeData['comments']` what's the problem? It's not an update it's a different question and the question is "*can I write the code for you*". Take direction and apply thought instead. Much more rewarding.

Comment: In the same vein, a little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?